# parameter pack must be expanded in this context after switching to Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++

Unfortunately after I switched to Visual Studio 2019 i've stumpled upon an error i just can't seem to fix.

Basically my program keeps telling me about a parameter pack i need to expand in this certain context. I've tried to look at various other posts but i just can't seem to understand it properly

Below you can see the error codes im getting

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KThhE.png

And here is the code that is outputting the error

```
template<std::uint64_t... Keys>
class key_list 
{
    template<std::size_t Index, std::uint64_t Key>
    static void _assign_single(XORSTR_VOLATILE std::uint64_t* buffer)
    {
        buffer[Index] = Key;
    }

public:
    template<std::size_t... Indices>
    static void assign(XORSTR_VOLATILE std::uint64_t* buffer, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
    {
        (_assign_single<Indices, Keys>(buffer) ...);
    }
};
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated :)

EDIT: Formatting

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Did you forget the `,` in your fold expression? `(_assign_single<Indices, Keys>(buffer) , ...);`

Comment: That was just an oversight by me, normally it was there but i forgot to add it back before i posted it here

Comment: Cannot reproduce, once that comma is added, see https://rextester.com/HGY71389

Answer (score 0):

```
   (_assign_single<Indices, Keys>(buffer) ...);
```

needs to be

```
   (_assign_single<Indices, Keys>(buffer), ...);
```

Comment: It was normally there but i forgot to add it back before i posted here, still no luck and the same errors are still appearing

Comment: @oliver Yet people cannot reproduce with the comma there.  Pkease generate a [mcve] that actually reproduces your issue and post another question with it.